# TouchJSON - Why I get lots of \U**** in the results of parsing?

Tags: iphone, ios, utf-8, touchjson

I am using TouchJSON to parse a JSON data.

In the results, the strings in the array are all in \U**** format.

Yes, they are meant to be other languages than English.

Why TouchJSON can't just replace them with real string via UTF8?

How should I deal with the results if I want to store them as NSStrings and use them in UILabel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading \u should not be a part of the string, but rather an identifier. If you load an NSString from parsed NSDictionary, it should've ignored the leading \u.

If it did not, you can always use `[theString substringFromIndex: 2]` to remove any leading identifiers.

Otherwise, take a look at [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/), an alternative library for Objective-C JSON parsing.